# Why is there no standardized wiki markup language?

Tags: wiki, markup

For as many wiki tools as I have used, each time I must learn yet another markup language.  Why doesn't wiki markup get standardized like HTML, XSLT, SVG, and other web languages?

Comment: Starting with XWiki Enterprise 1.6 it's possible to configure the Wiki syntaxes that are available to the user. http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Configuration#HConfiguringWikiSyntaxesanddefaultSyntax

Answer (score 8):

1. No standard libraries--unlike, say, RegEx, which is baked into various platforms, which tends to stabilize the de facto standards. There are standard *implementations*, such as MediaWiki, but not everyone wants to use MediaWiki and there's little incentive to copy its rather robust markup language.
2. Little need to exchange data between wiki platforms.
3. Few common users interact with multiple wikis, so they learn the ones they are exposed to.
4. Wiki markup is essentially a hack to overcome poor rich text browser control implementations, but rich text controls are getting better. (Templating via wiki markup is, of course, a whole other topic.)
5. Wikis are often domain-specific, so the available formatting options, suitable characters for markup, etc. differs between implementations.
6. There are existing competing "standards" such as BBcode, which further confuse the whole tag-vs-character-markup decisions.
7. If an entity such as the W3C came up with a standard, it would take 3 years to develop, an extra associate's degree to use, and no one would rewrite their wikis to support it.

Comment: +1 because wiki markup is essentially a hack. I tend to agree.

Answer (score 6):

There is - Its called [Creole](http://wikicreole.org). Most wikis accept that, as an extension or as a patch.

Answer (score 4):

Because *the beauty of standards is that there are so many you can choose from* (Torvalds), so it would not make a difference anyway.

There's a more or less *de facto* standard, which is MediaWiki. Other systems take advantage of their own solution to the problem in order to simplify parsing, or provide additional features that would not work with another syntax.

The main problem of lack of standards in this sense is portability. If you want to move from, say, MediaWiki to MoinMoin or wikkawiki, not only you have to convert the database, but also its content. That's caustic, but I think a stable standard will eventually evolve with natural selection. As I said, MediaWiki is more or less the standard, as it's very popular. Other solutions will become obsolete eventually. I mean.. check on [wikimatrix](http://www.wikimatrix.org/)... there are so many that it triggers the paradox of choice.

Comment: Thank you for the WikiMatrix URL! (e.g. http://www.wikimatrix.org/compare/DokuWiki+MediaWiki) which answers my questions ...

Comment: That quote far predates Torvalds

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's because any particular piece of wiki content doesn't need to interoperate with multiple wiki systems, in the way that an HTML file needs to be processed by multiple browsers, so there hasn't been an impetus to form a standards committee etc. etc.

Comment: Isn't that like saying that C could have a different version for each operating system since the executables aren't inoperable anyway.

Comment: There is one good reason for a (most of time commercial) wiki engine to talk/understand other wiki languages: facilitating adoption and/or migration. So, Confluence has an Universal Wiki Converter (http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Universal+Wiki+Converter), XWiki is working on something similar (http://gsoc.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Import+Export+other+wikis/Import+Export+from+any+other+Wiki), XWiki supports various wiki syntax (http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Configuration#HConfiguringWikiSyntaxesanddefaultSyntax)

Comment: @dacracot No, because you'd still want to compile the same source to different platforms, which you rarely want to do with wiki markup (except in the case of migration, per Pascal).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say people who come up with new variants all the time think the existing ones blows... and they may be correct.

Some well-defined stuff could be used to draw from like Tex but it doesn't seem like anyone think it's important with markup - though it ought to be one of the best ways to separate content from presentation.

Personally I'm not crazy for Markdown for instance and have been pondering back and forth for probably over two years between using it anyway, lately because of Showdown, or going through the trouble of creating a client-side version of one of my favorite markup variants instead. SO has shown that it might be neat enough, at least after their contributions to wmd - making it easier to use and configure. It would be neat for a wiki markup to add some intellisense-style typing/editing for linking to existing pages and resources ^^

Answer (score 1):

Wikis are *new*. It takes time to shake down a lot of ideas and learn (by trial and error the only way that really works when people are involved) what *works*.

Comment: Wikis are new ?!? Not really, the first wiki is 15 years old: "WikiWikiWeb was the first site to be called a wiki.[6] Ward Cunningham started developing WikiWikiWeb in 1994, and installed it on the Internet domain c2.com on March 25, 1995." Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki#History

Comment: A mere 15 years *is* new on the scale of technological development. It takes decades for each new paradigm to come to fruition. Recall the object orient programming was invented in the 1960s, and people are *still* thrashing out the best practices for it.

Comment: I agree that Wiki is more or less 'new' ;-) e.g. HTML is older than Wiki ;-) "Wiki" got popular after Wikipedia was founded 2003: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikimedia

Answer (score 1):

Another reason for the differences is that Wiki markup was designed to be easier to use than HTML, but different Wikis prefer a different spot on the power vs ease curve.  Just like there are so many Linux distributions because some people want more cutting-edge versions of packages while others want stability.  There's no right answer.

Answer (score 1):

What's the advantage of interoperability for companies that make wikis? Not much that I can see beyond marketing.

Answer (score 0):

When the day arrives that there is a logical or profitable reason for there to be a standard for wiki markup one will emerge. Until that day we are in the dark ages still stumbling along through the dark hoping for a better future.